# Is there a standard/elegant way of achieving Firebase-like reactive objects without Firebase?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js

The thing i like about realtime databases like Firebase is their push features. for example vuefire makes it incredibly simple to have self-updating objects without stringing up hundreds of socket listeners and callbacks.

This is an example:

```
data(){
  return {
    books: []
  }
},

created(){
  axios.get('/books', (books) => {
    this.books = books
  })
}
```

In order to add db reactivity to this, I need at least 3 events “book-created”, “book-updated”, “book-removed”.

```
Pusher.on('book-created', (book) {
  this.books.push(book)
})
Pusher.on('book-updated', (book) {
  let b = _.find(this.books, {id: book.id})

  if(b){
   _.extend(b, book)
  } 
})
etc..
```

It gets quite hairy when you have many models and many views, some views have a different set of books so I can’t just have one standard books vuex variable. Is there a sensible/fast way to approach this?

I can certainly abstract the event sending on my backend so all my models push events automatically. but the front-end is where i’m confused.

Answer (score 6):

I never worked with pusher before, and I don't know exactly what's the "different set of books" you're referring to, but I think I can give you some starting point to make your code look a bit more elegant.

The first thing I suggest; *do not try to reinvent the wheel*, use [**component mixins**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html). Just create a mixin like you'd normally consume your backend, make it work with some dynamic options (that you can set in the component's `data()`) and import it on every component you need the same functionality, with different options.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0nmvh2ct/) (you'll need to adapt it accordingly)

```
// Create an ES6 module and export this function, or the whole mixin
// (in that case export the mixin instead)
const initPusher = function ({pusher, collection, key, events}, component) {
  collection = component[collection]
  
  pusher.on(events.created, (record) => {
    collection.push(record)
  })
  
  pusher.on(events.updated, (record) => {
    let r = _.find(collection, {[key]: record[key]})

    if(r){
     _.extend(r, record)
    } 
  })
}

const PusherMixin = {
  methods: {
    // You can add some common methods for all your
    // components making use of this mixin
  },
  created () {
    initPusher(Object.assign({}, {
      pusher: Pusher,
      collection: 'collection',
      key: 'id',
      events: {
        created: 'book-created',
        updated: 'book-updated'
      }
    }, this.pusherOptions), this)
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mixins: [PusherMixin],
  data () {
    return {
      books: [],
      pusherOptions: {
        collection: 'books',
        key: 'id',
        events: {
          created: 'book-created',
          updated: 'book-updated'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

My second suggestion implied a manipulated array prototype with some custom methods and hooks to trigger events and XHRequests but after finishing the code for the mixin, I found out that extending the array's prototype with more methods was adding too much complexity, and a good mixin was totally the opposite of that.

If you want to go deeper, you may want to pay a look to RxJS and observables. You can build something on top of that with Pusher to get something like a Firebase real time object.

- Tutorial:
  https://blog.pusher.com/building-realtime-applications-with-cyclejs-and-rxjs/
- RxJS: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/
- Official implementation for Vue:
  https://github.com/vuejs/vue-rx